# Facebook button count on my site via javascript

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I´m trying to place a Facebook button - count on a site.

I´m building the site all the way through javascript.

So I´m adding an iframe inside a div (created through javascript) created used createElement('iframe'). I´ve added the iframe properties as the code I got from facebook page.
The problem is:

In the src iframe property, I have layout setted as 'button_count' (as I want a button_count layout for the site), but it appears as 'standard' layout.

Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi all. I´ve just changed the src to another one and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve just changed the src to another one and now it works :)